# Netsuite FreeMarker How to split String and Use the Index

Tags: html, string, netsuite, freemarker

I am new in NetSuite Technical, I am customizing the Invoice and Our Customer is using mix language in their Data Arabic & English together in the same Field, So if I use NotoSansArabic it will not Show the English Letters and If I remove the font; The Arabic Letters will not be shown properly. 
so, I want to split the String in the Field to Show Each set of Language in the Invoice/report.

I want to split the field where the Character "-" is appeared to set the font for the first Splitted String NotoSanArabic and keep the second set normal

I want to do something like this

```
<td>
   <#assign CustName={ record.entity} ? split( "-")>
   </#assign>
   CustName[0]
   <!--Can I read the Index of the First Splitted String-->
   CustName[1]
</td>
```

I will set the font for the index 0 to arabic and Keep the Index 1 as normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<#assign CustName=record.entity?split("-")>
${CustName[0]}
${CustName[1]}
```

However, this only works as expected if there's always exactly one `-` in the name. If that's not the case (and especially if there can be 0 `-` in it), then do this instead:

```
${record.entity?keep_before('-')}
${record.entity?keep_after('-')}
```